# How do I add files to a git project without them being tracked?

Tags: git

I have downloaded a repo from github to a dev server. The repo does not have a media/ dir. I copied the media/ folder from the live site to the dev site, however, git picked it up. So now when I try to pull files, I'm out of sync.

So I added media/ to the .gitignore file (which is in VC). The problem is, that git now tracks the changes to that, and I still cannot do a git pull.

This server will only ever pull files.

What's the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: It seems like your title and body are asking different questions. The title is asking how to add files to a git directory without tracking them, whereas if I understand correctly, the body is asking how to stop git from tracking a file that you don't want tracked. Which is it? (Also, what exactly do you mean when you say "git picked it up"? A brief transcript from the terminal showing what happens when you try to pull would be helpful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understand it, you want to exclude a directory from version control in your own private copy of a repo. This is easy: there are two places that Git looks for paths to ignore, the `.gitignore` file (which is usually tracked in the project commit history), and `.git/info/exclude` (which is private to your copy of the repo). Add the path you want to exclude to the latter, and that will avoid problems pulling from the server in future.